# Difference between scala concurrent and non concurrent class under parallelsim

Tags: scala, memory, concurrency, parallel-processing

In Scala - functional programming course on coursera, the following snippet is described to fail in the concurrent case. The snippet will succeed if the `mutable.Set` is replaced with a concurrent class.

```
def intersection(a: GenSet[Int], b: GenSet[Int]): Set[Int] = {
val result = mutable.Set[Int]()
for (x <- a) if (b contains x) result += x
result
}
intersection((0 until 1000).toSet, (0 until 1000 by 4).toSet)
intersection((0 until 1000).par.toSet, (0 until 1000 by 4).par.toSet)
```

> Rule: Avoid mutations to the same memory locations without proper
>   synchronization.

What is the difference between the concurrent and non-concurrent class, or what is the reason that the non-concurrent class can fail under parallelism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When concurrently append element to **Set** without **synchronization**, the **Set** can't handle the **collisions** correctly or calculate position wrongly. so for your example, the `res2` maybe will have **duplicate fields** or less some fields.

Explantation:

for:

```
for (x <- a) if (b contains x) result += x
result
}
```

There is a **race condition** for `result += x`. it equals to [result.addEntry(x)](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/9acab45aeeadef2f63da69faf81465cc15599789/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/FlatHashTable.scala#L148), but for this method it's not **thread safe**,

```
var h = index(newEntry.hashCode)
var curEntry = table(h)
while (null != curEntry) {
  if (curEntry == newEntry) return false
  h = (h + 1) % table.length
  curEntry = table(h)
  //Statistics.collisions += 1
}
table(h) = newEntry
```

In the above code, when try to concurrently append element to **HashTable**. it's maybe caused calculate wrong position or meet wrong collisions. For example, when try to add `newEntry` to the `Set`, actually it's not exist in the **set**, it will directly go to `table(h) = newEntry`, but at the same time, there is a new value, it has the same `hashcode` with the `newEntry`, but for the first `newEntry` still not finish `table(h) = newEntry`, so the `newEntry` will be override by the **second** value.

so for the **synchronization** maybe you can do it like:

```
for (x <- a) {
  if (b contains x) {
    this.synchronized {
      result += x
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is probably good enough to have `result.synchronized` (so that multiple calls to `intersection` -- and possibly other method in this class -- can still proceed in parallel)

Answer (score 1):

If your code contains mutable fields, then it is not thread safe. That means, you cannot execute this code **concurrently**. Concurrent execution means, executing same code in several thread at the same time.

So, lets start with your given code, since it contains a mutable field `result`, and this field is modified/mutated inside `for` loop.

```
def intersection(a: GenSet[Int], b: GenSet[Int]): Set[Int] = {
val result = mutable.Set[Int]() //This field is not thread safe.
    for (x <- a) if (b contains x) result += x      //mutation occured here.
    result
}
```

Now, lets see what happen in execution of first case: `intersection((0 until 1000).toSet, (0 until 1000 by 4).toSet)`. Here, you have provide Set with value `0 to 1000`. Now, in `for loop`, when this set is iterated, the execution will be sequential. i.e. value of `x` is written to result sequentially from `0 till 1000`. Hence, the code execute without any error.

Now, lets see the second scenario, `intersection((0 until 1000).par.toSet, (0 until 1000 by 4).par.toSet)`. In this case, the set you provide is `Parallel set`. Hence, in `for loop`, *mutation/write to result field occur concurrently*. Hence, there will be a **race condition** between threads in order to write data and hence this execution is not thread safe and will fail. To avoid this problem, write access to result must be synchronized as described in other answer, otherwise, it will not be thread safe.

Therefore, there is a rule for concurrency:

> "Avoid mutations to the same memory locations without proper
>   synchronization".